# Windows10 ubuntu bash: chromedriver can not initiate Chrome?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use `chromeriver` to fetch some url. But It is not working.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#from langdetect import detect, DetectorFactory

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

which gives me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

It apparently can't start the Chrome.

If I uncomment this line in the code:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

It stops working and I have to break it with `ctrl + C`
which shows this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/payman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 379, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 14, in <module>
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/payman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/home/payman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/payman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 326, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/payman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/payman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

My chromedriver executable is stored in the this directory `\usr`
and so in the `.bashrc` I have added:
`export PATH="/usr:$PATH"`

I have followed the installations on this page:

[How to Setup Selenium with ChromeDriver on Ubuntu 18.04 & 16.04](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: You are trying to run `selenium` within the ubuntu bash shell in win10?  You installed `xvfb`?

Comment: well actually no. haven't even heard of it. but believe me this is not my fault. it wasn't mentoned anywhere. what is that? i'll have a look of course

Comment: and yes btw, I am trying to run it on ubuntu bash in win10

Comment: It's the first step in the article that you linked...

Comment: I see. so I have installed it already. but it is not working. do you have any ideas?

Comment: Not enough information.  I'd advise starting from step one, go thru each step to make certain it's complete, and see what you missed.